# Call to a member function expectsOutput() on integer when testing artisan console command

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a very simple example to show the problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class VendorCounts extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'vendor:counts
                            {year : The year of vendor counts}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Runs vendor counts';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Starting Vendor Counts');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Console\Vendor;

use Tests\TestCase;

class VendorCountsTest extends TestCase {

    public function testVendorCounts()
    {
        $this->artisan('vendor:counts', ['year' => 2019])
             ->expectsOutput('Starting Vendor Counts')
             ->assertExitCode(0);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Console\Vendor\VendorCountsTest::testVendorCounts
Error: Call to a member function expectsOutput() on integer

/Users/albertski/Sites/vrs/tests/Feature/Console/Vendor/VendorCountsTest.php:12
```

I know the command definitely runs because if I put a dump statement in it shows the debug output.

I am using Laravel 6.3.  Is there a different way to test this?

Comment: was this an upgrade to Laravel 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was using was that `TestCase` was using `Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase` as `BaseTestCase`.  I ended up creating another Base just for console commands.

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class ConsoleTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to your `VendorCountsTest` class:

```
public $mockConsoleOutput = true;
```

This is set by a trait but just making sure something hasn't changed the value. When `$mockConsoleOutput` is `false` it will directly run the artisan commmand. When it is `true` it will wrap it in a `PendingCommand` object that has those methods you are trying to call.

Comment: Hmm just tried that but it did not work. Same issue.

Comment: based on the library code you would have to figure out why that variable is ending up as `false` ... did you alter the base test class you are using?

Comment: Ahh that was it. I am using `BrowserKitTesting`. Once I switched to default the issue went away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the use of `expectedOutput()` on my Artisan class would fail all the time, which turned out to be because I had used `exit()` and/or `die()` in a method, which really did not work well with phpunit test methods.

So if you want to stop processing the "script" at some point, just use an empty `return` and not `exit()` or `die()` if you want to utilize the built-in `->artisan()` testing in Laravel.

## Working example:

```php
<?php
// app/Console/Commands/FooCommand.php
public function handle()
{
  $file = $this->argument('file');
  
  if (! file_exists($file)) {
    $this->line('Error! File does not exist!');
    return;
  }
}

// tests/Feature/FooCommandTest.php
public function testFoo() {
  $this->artisan('foo', ['file' => 'foo.txt'])->expectsOutput('Something');
}
```

## Non-working example:

```php
<?php
// app/Console/Commands/FooCommand.php
public function handle()
{
  $file = $this->argument('file');
  
  if (! file_exists($file)) {
    $this->line('Error! File does not exist!');
    exit;
  }
}

// tests/Feature/FooCommandTest.php
public function testFoo() {
  $this->artisan('foo', ['file' => 'foo.txt'])->expectsOutput('Something');
}
```